# FullCalendar agendaWeek/agendaDay view, width of time row

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have a probleme of the setting of my calendar now. I want to make first row which is the time in AgendaWeek view and AgendaDay view a little wider, but i can't find the corresponding css code in fullcalendar.css. Can someone help me?[image]

Comment: how about using slotWidth

Comment: @krisph: Thank you for the response. But it doesn't change at all when i put "slotWidth: 20, "into the code

Comment: @krisph slotWidth is specific to the timeline view in the Scheduler plugin. It affects the width of actual event timeslots, not the left-hand column. And it doesn't apply to agenda views. Read the docs more carefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By inspecting the source of a calendar of mine I can see the following code for each time displayed in the left-hand column:

```
<td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 55px;">
  <span>12:35am</span>
</td>
```

The width appears to be set inline. Presumably this is done via some code in fullCalendar.

You can override it in CSS, but you also need to shift all the other `<td>`s in the column as well, not of all which have the same combination of classes.

Fortunately, they do all have the same root class - `.fc-axis`. Therefore, if you add this to the end of your CSS, it should adjust the width for you quite happily.

```
.fc-axis { width: 100px !important;}
```

Having said that, beware of fixed widths and how fullCalendar will react if you resize it, or resize the browser window, depending whether you've given your calendar a fixed width/height, or messed with the aspectRatio settings.

Comment: Prefect. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. I hope your users like bright orange! :-p

Comment: @ADyson the orange one was hilarious !!

Comment: That should do it, but still wonder, what "some code" produces the inline and its purpose

Comment: @Fanky it would be somewhere in the source code of fullCalendar. I don't know where that is - I am not a developer of fullCalendar. You'd have to inspect the relevant source code yourself to discover that. However, I imagine the purpose of it is to keep the calendar grid accurate and all lined up. Remember that the events are overlaid on top of the grid (rather than held within cells), and the grid itself is actually an overlay of two separate HTML layouts. Therefore a consistent, predictable width will be required in order to ensure the events can be positioned correctly on top of it.

Comment: my resources got shifted, because the first, empty th, upon times, was empty and an empty `display:table-cell` doesn't depend on set `width`.. I had to do `.fc-axis:after{min-width:100px;content:"";display: block;}`

Comment: @Fanky which version of fullcalendar? This answer is only tested on v3. As far as I remember (it's been a while), there are no `<th>` elements involved. As you saw in what I answered, there is only a `<td>`. Can you be more specific about the problem, and/or make a demo which shows the necessity for your suggestion?

Comment: 4.1.0, but with resourceTimeGridDay view, sorry for not mentioning that!